# Indexing multidimensional numpy-array with list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a problem accessing the data in a multidimensional numpy-array with python 2.7. The goal is to read multiple values whose positions are stored in a list.

```
import numpy as np
matrix=np.ones((10,30,5))

positions=[]
positions.append([1,2,3])
positions.append([4,5,6])

for i in positions:
    print matrix[i]
```

What I want is:

```
print matrix[1,2,3]
```

But I get:

```
print [matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3]]
```

Could you please give me a hint for the correct indexing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [indexing docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing):

> In Python, `x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)]` is equivalent to `x[exp1, exp2,..., expN];` the
>   latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

So, instead of passing it a list, pass a tuple to `matrix`:

```
for i in positions:
    print matrix[tuple(i)]
```

Lists are used for picking item at particular indices, i.e [index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays):

```
>>> arr = np.random.rand(10)
>>> arr
array([ 0.56854322,  0.21189256,  0.72516831,  0.85751778,  0.29589961,
        0.90989207,  0.26840669,  0.02999548,  0.65572606,  0.49436744])
>>> arr[[0, 0, 5, 1, 5]]
array([ 0.56854322,  0.56854322,  0.90989207,  0.21189256,  0.90989207])
```

Comment: First answer after 4 minutes. I was sure it's a simple question, but just couldn't the solution. It's something that's missing in the Scipy docs. Thank you Ashwini!

Comment: @Kaioto They have covered it here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing

The NumPy's tentative tutorial is down at the moment for me, so possibly there as well.